# Determine if function return value is a dplyr object

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I am loading other R files using `source`. Using `do.call`, I am calling a particular function from that R file, passing it the arguments. I would like to check that the thing *returned* from the function is in fact a dplyr object, before trying to call `write.csv` on it.

I tried using `typeof` on the result, but it looks like I just get back `list`. Is there something along the lines of `is.data.frame` that I can use? If I can, I am just going to end up calling `stop` anyway, but it'd be nice to provide a nicer error message in that case, rather than whatever `write.csv` spits out.

For example, given this R script, is there anyway to tell if the returned object is a dplyr object?

```
library(dplyr)

dm_usa <- function(dm, caseSensitive) {
    if (caseSensitive) {
        dplyr::filter(dm, COUNTRY == "USA")
    } else {
        dplyr::filter(dm, tolower(COUNTRY) == "usa")
    }
}
```

The `dm` argument was constructed using: `dplyr::tbl(connection, tableName)`, using dbplyr under the hood.

Comment: Perhaps the best/simplest test would be `inherits(ret, "data.frame")` (as it will match true for `tbl_df`, `data.table`, and good-ole `data.frame` by itself).

Comment: @r2evans, post as answer?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest keeping it simple: `inherits(ret, "data.frame")`.

While `dplyr` and friends tend to advertise the `"tbl_df"` a lot, they can still work with and return `data.table` and vanilla `data.frame` without re-classing it (depending on the operations). Since all of them are really multi-class:

```r
class(tibble::tibble(mtcars))
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
class(data.table::data.table(mtcars))
# [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
class(mtcars)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

the use of `inherits` allows one to pick *any* of the available class strings, and `"data.frame"` will match all three. (This is in contrast to an anti-pattern of `class(obj) == "..."`, since that works only if object is a single-class object, where two of the three above will not work as desired.)

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: Do you know if this will work for both `dbplyr` and `dtplyr`? I am going to update the question above to give more context.

Comment: The answer demonstrates that it works when the returned object is classed from `data.table` and `dplyr` as well as base R's `data.frame`. If a frame is grouped, it still inherits from `data.frame`. If a group is row-wise, it still inherits from `data.frame`. The bottom line: you need your object to be something you can pass to `write.csv`, and I know of no object that `dplyr` verbs will return that does not inherit from `data.frame`; any other classes present (e.g., `tbl_df`, `group_df`) do not affect this.

Comment: The only way a dplyr verb can return something else is if it's still in "lazy evaluation" mode, is that what you're trying to fix?

Comment: I'm not sure if that question was directed to me, but I know I can pass the result of that `filter` call to `write.csv` and it works. I am just worried someone will return a number, string or something nonsensical. Worst case `write.csv` throws an error.

Comment: Yes it is directed to you. Does `inherit` not work in a situation you've seen? Afaict, it's the most canonical approach to your question of how to know if a function returns something that `write.csv` requires.

Comment: `inherits` did not work when I tried last night, neither did `is.data.frame`, but `write.csv` is definitely working. Is dplyr providing its own implementation of `write.csv` perhaps?

Comment: No. The tidyverse way of writing tabular data is typically `readr::write_csv` (and others). I don't understand how `inherits(dat, "data.frame")` does not work. How are you using it such that it fails? When I try on sample data with your given function, it works, so there must be something we don't see that is causing a problem.

Comment: I clearly need to do more homework. I will read up on `readr::write_csv`. My guess is the call to `write.csv` works because internally it is calling `as.data.frame` or something (which is not good). I doubt me running a function loaded via `source` would cause this issue, so there's something more at play (perhaps dbplyr???). Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248488/discussion-between-r2evans-and-travis-parks).